# Loading a css file dynamically? Code inside

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following code in my `<head>`

```
<% if(Context.User.IsInRole("Reseller")) {%>
<link href="<%: themelocation %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<%} else {%>
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<%} %>
```

The issue is with themelocation, which is declared just above this block of code - like so:

```
<%
    var reseller = new Reseller();
    var storeSettings = new StoreSettings();
    var themelocation = "";
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var resellerRepository = new ResellerRepository();
        reseller = resellerRepository.GetResellerByUsername(Context.User.Identity.Name);

        var storeSettingsRepository = new StoreSettingsRepository();
        storeSettings = storeSettingsRepository.GetStoreSettings((int) reseller.StoreSettingsID);

        themelocation = storeSettings.Theme.StylesheetLocation;
    }
%>
```

Setting a break point shows that themelocation holds the string I need, but when the page is run - it generates a 400 - Bad Request error, and the net tab in firebug reveals its looking for this:

```
http://localhost:50982/%3C%:%20themelocation%20%%3E
```

Where am I going wrong here? Why is it using the variable name, and not what it contains?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC2, and all of this code is located on my master page.

Comment: is there any difference whether you use : or = ?

Comment: nope. doesn't appear so, it was = before.

Comment: so you mean replacing it with = sign didn't solved the problem

Comment: correct - it doesn't matter if its : or =, i get the same results.

Comment: do you have runat='server' in the head declaration?

Comment: try removing it, I had the similar issue, but I don't remember how I fixed it.

Comment: That worked! post it as an answer for the rep.

Comment: Is the code you posted located in your view??? Repository access inside a view??? Dude, that's not how MVC was intended to work :-)

Comment: I replaced the repository calls with an action, thanks for pointing out the bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what Artem K. suggested and removed runat='server' from the  and the code executed properly.

Comment: yeah, since this is MVC we don't work with server controls and runat="server"